# How do I properly test reflection-based Java library?

Tags: java, testing, reflection, mockito

I have created my custom library that adds a lot of mechanics on basis of Annotations including reading methods' arguments, theirs names and return types. I also wanted to test the code, but there appeared such problems, i.e., how to test if a certain method passed as an argument has been called? Mocking methods is not supported by Mockito because it uses methods' objects under the hood. But for my library there is no other possibility, or I don't see any. Another example is checking if passed consumer has been called with correct arguments. In general, I shouldn't mock classes from `java.lang.*`, but don't see any other way of reliable testing.

Assume the following code that only uses my library:

```java
public class TestedClass {
    public String specialMethod(boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            return null;
        }
        return "test";
    }
}

// some main
Libraty<TestedClass> library = MyLibraty.register(TestedClass.class);
library.setOnNullListener(myObject -> myObject.register("null"));
```

My library automatically checks if the method returns `null` and if so, calls the created `Consumer`. Adding a concrete `Consumer` is out of scope and is in the responsibility of the app that uses my library.

How do I test if this behavior is correct without mocking `Method` or `Consumer`?

Comment: I'm not clear whether you want to unit test the behaviour of your library, or whether you are unit testing a class in an application which happens to use your library.

Comment: @tgdavies I want to test behavior of my library only

Comment: Is there any need to mock anything in that case?

Comment: How do I test if my Consumer has been executed?

Comment: You can certainly mock the consumer, or just pass one which sets a flag.